# Should I use the German-US tax treaty as a researcher in Boston?

Tags: usa, taxes, german-citizens, tax-treaties

I am postdoc in Boston (USA) doing research for the benefit of the public, and I'm from Germany.

I receive a normal salary from my university in Boston (not a stipend).

I'm on a J1 visa since July 2018.

Now for the tax report I need to decide if I want to use the German-US tax treaty.

If I use it, I will get the federal income tax back, as the online tax reporting tool (Windstar) tells me: https://trr.thomsonreuters.com/

Tax in Germany is generally higher for my case than US tax. But do I have to pay taxes at all if I use the tax treaty? Or do I have to pay later when I am back in Germany?

I don't know how long I will be here, but probably altogether around 3-5 years.

Comment: I found [the treaty](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/germany.pdf) and [a summary](http://www.hauswiesner.com/Tax%20Treaty%20Germany_USA_Basics.pdf) but I haven't figured it out. Hope someone can find the answer!

Comment: @krubo: Thank you very much for having tried to look into this, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: IIRC from when my French wife was on J-1 in the USA, the first 1 (or 2?) years you don't need to pay (federal) tax at all, but I don't know the specifics.